# Is "Black Caucus" really called Black Caucus?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

In House of Cards, Frank Underwood convinces Black Caucus to play a political trick.

I am wondering if "Black Caucus" is really called "Black Caucus", as it seems a bit politically incorrect.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_Black_Caucus

Comment: There is a long and complicated history of describing African Americans. For example, there is an organization called “The National Association for the Advancement of Colored People”, which no one had a problem with, but it is considered very rude to refer to an African American as “colored”. This is how the culture is in the USA, not necessarily anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's officially called the "[Congressional Black Caucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_Black_Caucus)", if that makes it more plausible-sounding to you.